# How to detect ios push notification permissions/settings programmatically

Tags: ios, permissions, notifications, settings

In Notification settings (Settings->Notifications->AnyAppName), there are 5 items and each has a switch button, `Sounds`,`Badge App Icon`, `Show on Lock Screen`, `Show in History`, `Show as Banners`.

I am using `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings] types]` to get user's settings and promote corresponding alert to use.
It may return value `0~7` represents any combination of `Sound`, `Badge` and `Banners`. The question is, are we able to detect the states of `Show on Lock Screen`, `Show in History`?

Also, at the bottom of the setting page, theres is an `OPTIONS` option called `Show Previews`, it has three options: `Always(Default)`, `When Unlocked` and `Never`. Are we able to get user's setting programmatically for this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the UserNotifications framework, supported starting from iOS 10.
This will allow you to retrieve `UNNotificationSettings` via the `getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:` function of `UNUserNotificationCenter`.
In `UNNotificationSettings` you can check some values:

- notificationCenterSetting (`Show in History`)
- lockScreenSetting (`Show on Lock Screen`)
- alertSetting (`Show as Banners`)
- alertStyle (the type of the banner)

For instance:

```
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings * _Nonnull settings) {
    if(settings.authorizationStatus == UNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        //notifications are enabled for this app

        if(settings.notificationCenterSetting == UNNotificationSettingEnabled ||
          settings.lockScreenSetting == UNNotificationSettingEnabled ||
          (settings.alertSetting == UNNotificationSettingEnabled && settings.alertStyle != UNAlertStyleNone)) {
            //the user will be able to see the notifications (on the lock screen, in history and/or via banners)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){

                //now for instance, register for remote notifications
                //execute this from the main queue
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
            });
        }
        else {
            //the user must change notification settings in order te receive notifications
        }
    }
    else {
        //request authorization
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionBadge | UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if(granted) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){

                    //now for instance, register for remote notifications
                    //execute this from the main queue
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
                });
            }
            else {
                //user denied the authorization request
                //the user must change notification settings in order te receive notifications
            }
        }
    }
}];
```